# CouchDB/Cradle How do I reverse the default sorting?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

so I'm using couchDB/Cradle/and Node JS to build a simple blogging system. I want to sort the posts by date, so I used emit(docs.created_at,docs) to do so using CouchDB's default sorting system. This works, but it places the most recent posts at the bottom instead of the top. How do i reverse this? I've looked all over, and i know you can do "descending=true", but where would I insert this statement in Cradle? In addition, the date is stored as a number format like 04-05-2011-3432:#324, how would I convert that to output the date as April 5th,2011 on the HTML page.

Thanks, I know this is probably rediculously easy, I'm just starting out and am a total couchDB/NodeJS Noob. <.<

Comment: Regarding the date format - try asking it as a separate question with JavaScript and couchdb tags.

Answer (score 2):

> where would I insert this statement in
>   Cradle?

Try to pass `descending=true` as a view parameter, for example:

```
db.view('characters/all', {descending: true}, function (err, res) {
    res.forEach(function (row) {
        sys.puts(row.name + " is on the " +
                 row.force + " side of the force.");
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated the answer example, try passing it as an object parameter.

Comment: THANKSSSS SOOOO MUCH. It works! I spent way too long guessing and checking where to put it. By chance, why do you need to pass it as an object?

Comment: It's an configuration object which represents options that will be used when querying your view. If it's passed as an object then you can add more properties to it, for example descending, startkey, endkey, ...